# CDiscount: Problem sending a JSON Get request through Postman

Tags: api, postman

I've been trying to send a GET request to CDiscount's GetProducts API by using the Json format provided by the documentation and have been met with an Error: read ECONNRESET.
I use the Raw (set to JSON) window in Body to send this request.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET request doesn't send Body content. Only for POST and PUT send body.